# Illustrator: How to create a circular arc with rounded edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

I am trying to draw a circular arc with rounded edges like in the picture below, but I failed miserably. Could anyone please help with step by step explanation ?!

[image: circular arc with rounded edges]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a circle.

Delete 2 anchor points on the circle

Apply a thick stroke

Set the stroke options (on the Stroke Panel) to have rounded end caps.

[image]

Pressing F1 and reviewing the help files may be helpful. These are *very* basic operations for Illustrator.

Comment: Scott, thanks a lot, but excuse my ignorance, how to delete 2 anchor points on the circle? I'm a total noob.

Comment: Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (The White Arrow) click an anchor and hit the **Delete** key. You *really* should review the help files. Deleting anchor points is an exceptionally basic operation. While I appreciate the desire to learn. StackExchange sites aren't really geared to teaching software *basics*.